# How to sort a array of object based on a key and set an addition key which should increment upon change in sequence?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array which should be sorted based on conditionalTo and set a index based on the sequence, whenever the sequence is changed index should be incremented. once this is done we need to sort the array again based on computationTo within the index only second level sorting should happen

```
const array = 
[
{conditionalFrom: 102, conditionalTo: 112, computationFrom: 10, computationTo: 150},
{conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 100, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 400},
{conditionalFrom: 10, conditionalTo: 100, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 300},
{conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 110, computationFrom: 20, computationTo: 200},
{conditionalFrom: 12, conditionalTo: 112, computationFrom: 100, computationTo: 1000},
{conditionalFrom: 100, conditionalTo: 110, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000},
]
```

sorted based on conditionalTo and added number for each sequence

```
const sorted = 
[
{conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 100, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 400, sequece: 1},
{conditionalFrom: 10, conditionalTo: 100, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 300, sequece: 1},
{conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 110, computationFrom: 20, computationTo: 200, sequece: 2},
{conditionalFrom: 100, conditionalTo: 110, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000, sequece: 2},
{conditionalFrom: 12, conditionalTo: 112, computationFrom: 100, computationTo: 1000, sequece: 3},
{conditionalFrom: 102, conditionalTo: 112, computationFrom: 10, computationTo: 150, sequece: 3},
]
```

sort based on computationTo and sequence

```
const sorted = 
[
{conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 100, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 400},
{conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 110, computationFrom: 20, computationTo: 200},
{conditionalFrom: 10, conditionalTo: 100, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 300},
{conditionalFrom: 12, conditionalTo: 112, computationFrom: 100, computationTo: 1000},
{conditionalFrom: 100, conditionalTo: 110, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000},
{conditionalFrom: 102, conditionalTo: 112, computationFrom: 10, computationTo: 150},
]
```

tried soo many methods including noramal sort lodash sortby orderby but nothing really worked pls help
Added sequence is actually a work around when nothing really worked

```
 const SlabDetails = orderBy(this.tableData, [r => r.conditionalTo - r.conditionalFrom, r => r.computationTo - r.computationFrom], "asc");
```

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820457/how-to-sort-a-array-of-object-based-on-two-properties-and-check-the-rage-is-sequ/67820668#67820668)

Comment: a common number for all sequence just added for differentiating while sorting second time, if sequence same it will have same sequence number otherwise increment, its actually a random  number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of it in the wrong order. You can `sort` the array based on `conditionalTo` and `computationTo` first. Then, add a `sequence` property to each object. Increment it if the `conditionalTo` is different compared to the previous object

```js
const array =[{conditionalFrom:102,conditionalTo:112,computationFrom:10,computationTo:150},{conditionalFrom:0,conditionalTo:100,computationFrom:0,computationTo:400},{conditionalFrom:10,conditionalTo:100,computationFrom:0,computationTo:300},{conditionalFrom:0,conditionalTo:110,computationFrom:20,computationTo:200},{conditionalFrom:12,conditionalTo:112,computationFrom:100,computationTo:1000},{conditionalFrom:100,conditionalTo:110,computationFrom:1001,computationTo:100000},];

array.sort((a,b) => a.conditionalTo - b.conditionalTo || a.computationTo - b.computationTo)

let previous,
    sequence = 0;
    
for (const o of array) {
  if (o.conditionalTo !== previous) {
    ++sequence;
    previous = o.conditionalTo
  } 
  o.sequence = sequence
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: there is change in result can u chk?